# React Native fetch: Cannot send a message. Unknown Websocket

Tags: android, react-native, websocket, fetch-api

I have a fairly complicated React-Native app. I use a combination of Android Studio emulators and Android device to debug, and always use remote debugging, live reload, and hot reloading.

Recently I began having an issue where fetch() calls cause a runtime error:

**"Cannot send a message. Unknown WebSocket id ."
send
WebSocketModule.java
...**

I have been using these api calls with fetch for months with no issues, and the calls work:

1. On emulator
2. On device, if NOT debugging remotely
3. Fail on device, IF debugging remotely

The only thing I can find that seems relevant is this:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1e8f3b11027fe0a7514b4fc97d0798d3c64bc895/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/websocket/WebSocketModule.java

**Why might my client be turning up null, or how else might I fix this so I can debug remotely without these WebSocket errors?**

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with remote-redux-devtools. Removing the devTools middleware fixed this issue in the interim, reference:
https://github.com/zalmoxisus/remote-redux-devtools/issues/4